# How do I show the latest Eclipse error log entry

Tags: eclipse

After creating a new entry in the Eclipse Error Log, I want it to be in view for the user, even if they had previously scrolled down in the log view.

```
org.osgi.framework.Bundle bundle = ...;
ILog log = myPlatform.getLog(bundle);
log.log(status);
```

Then I would like to make the UI view scroll to that new item, so that it is in view for the user. How would I go ahead to do that?

Comment: Just a hint, but doesn't simply calling `showView(errorLogViewId)` does that automatically?

Comment: @rlegendi Actually no. That does show the error view if it was closed, but does not scroll to the top. It looks like it scrolls to the previously selected log item though. I would like like to make sure that the top most log entry is in view.

Comment: Ah ok, glad to hear mate :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seems to not be any proper API to do this. I had to register a listener on logging and use reflection to actually make the top item scroll into view.

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    // other stuff here
    Platform.addLogListener(new ScrollToLatestLogListener());
}

public class ScrollToLatestLogListener implements ILogListener {

    @Override
    public void logging(IStatus status, String plugin) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                IViewPart part = getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView");
                if (part != null) {
                    ErrorLogAction action = new ErrorLogAction();
                    action.setActivePart(null, part);
                    action.run(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And luckily, a collegue had already implemented this, to do the real work:

```
public class ErrorLogAction implements IObjectActionDelegate, IViewActionDelegate {

    IWorkbenchPart part;

    public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
        part = targetPart;
    }

    public void run(IAction action) {
        try {
            Field treeField = part.getClass().getDeclaredField("fTree");
            treeField.setAccessible(true);
            Tree treeWidget = (Tree)(treeField.get(part));
            if(!treeWidget.isDisposed()) {
                TreeItem[] treeItems = treeWidget.getItems();
                if((treeItems != null) && (treeItems.length > 0)) {
                    treeWidget.setTopItem(treeItems[0]);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        part.getSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(null);
    }

    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    }

    public void init(IViewPart view) {
        part = view;
    }

}
```